# C struct with pointer to itself - accessing values

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a problem with structs. I must use a struct that has a pointer to itself. I have done this and I think it works:

```
typedef struct tag_t tag_t;
    struct tag_t{
    char name[15];
    int is_self_closing;
    tag_t *child;
};
```

I am making a function that adds a child to a tag, like "body" is a child of the **html** tag, so my program core dumped and resulted in a segmentation fault when I tried to work with the "name" and "is_self_closing" variables of the child pointer. I don't know how to access them correctly. This is the entire code for the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct tag_t tag_t;
struct tag_t{
    char name[15];
    int is_self_closing;
    tag_t *child;
};

void add_chilld(tag_t *,char[15],int);

void print_markup(tag_t);

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    tag_t parent,child;
    strcpy(child.name,"body");
    child.is_self_closing = 1;
    strcpy(parent.name,"html");
    parent.is_self_closing = 0;
    add_chilld(&parent,child.name,child.is_self_closing);
    printf("child name = %s child closing = %d\n",child.name,child.is_self_closing);
    printf("%s %d %s\n",parent.name,parent.is_self_closing,parent.child->name);
    return 0;
}

void add_chilld(tag_t *parent,char name[15],int is_self_closing){
    if(is_self_closing == 1){
        printf("parent name = %s\n",parent->child->name);
        strcpy(parent->child->name,name);
        parent->child->is_self_closing = is_self_closing;
    }else{
        parent->child = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: a) you're printing the child's name before assigning anything to it, as the parent's name. b) the child pointer is not pointing anywhere. c) `char name[15]` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `add_chilld()` function, you are attempting to access `parent->child` but you never made it point to anything valid.

So, you're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which holds an indeterminate value, i.e, an invalid memory address, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

In other words, before you can make use of something like `parent->child->name`, you need to make sure that the `child` member of the `parent` variable is actually set to some *child* (which you allocated earlier).

Comment: Reason for DV, anyone?